# How can I de-normalize a dataset which was normalized using an unknown scaling factor?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am using the dataset https://github.com/google-research/open-covid-19-data/blob/master/data/exports/search_trends_symptoms_dataset/README.md which is normalized in the following way (taken from their github in the url above):

1. First, the algorithm counts the number of searches for each symptom in that region for that day/week.
2. Next, we divide this count by the total number of Search users in the region for that day/week to calculate relative popularity (which can be interpreted as the probability that a user in this region will search for the given symptom on that day/week). We refer to this ratio as the normalized popularity of a symptom.
3. We then find the maximum value of the normalized popularity across the entire published time range for that region, over all symptoms using the chosen time resolution (day/week). We scale this maximum value to 100. All the other values are mapped to proportionally smaller values (linear scaling) in the range 0-100.
4. Finally, we store the scaling factor and use it to scale values (for the same region and time resolution) in subsequent releases. In future updates, when a symptom popularity exceeds the previously-observed maximum value (found in step 3), then the new scaled value will be larger than 100

The problem comes when I try to use the dataset to predict hospitalization cases. Since the relative popularity of a symptom depends on a state-dependent scaling factor, I cannot compare data across different states. So what I need to do is somehow denormalize the data to find the popularity of a symptom in general and not relative to a particular state.

My attempt at a solution involved finding the median relative popularity of a symptom across different states, as well as the median popularity of different symptoms in a certain state. I feel like using these medians could somehow help me recover the pre-normalization data but I am unsure how.

Here is an example:

Pre-normalization data which I am trying to recover:

```
         | Symptom 1 | Symptom 2 | Symptom 3 |

| State 1| 20/200  | 5/200    | 10/200  |

| State 2 | 30/100  | 1/100  | 20/100   |

| State 3 | 10/50  | 0/50 | 5/50    |
```

Post-normalization data which I have:

```
          | Symptom 1 | Symptom 2 | Symptom 3 |

| State 1 | 100       | 25        | 50        |

| State 2 | 100       | 3.33      | 66.67     |

| State 3 | 100       | 0         | 50        |
```

Comment: You mention that the scaling factor is stored. So does it mean the scaling factor is given along with the scaled data?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is mathematically impossible to recover the pre-normalised data given only the dataset. Despite Google storing the scaling factors, these scaling factors are not available to us, and without them we do not have enough information.

Consider the following values for a state:

```
100 | 25 | 50
```

This could mean, for any x s.t. 0 < x <= 1, this is a possible pre-normalisation result:

```
x | x/4 | x/2
```

Even if you had the scaling factor given to you and you could somehow figure out that x was equal to, say, 0.1: You would then still be unable to calculate whether it was 10/100, 20/200, 70/700, etc without the total number of users in each region. Hence it would be impossible to compare the regions.

Google have written this in their documentation just below the lines you quoted:

"...you should not compare the values of symptom popularity across regions or time resolutions — the region and time resolution specific scalings make these comparisons meaningless."

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes I agree the original data cannot mathematically be recovered but I was wondering if there was a way to approximate it so that regression can be performed on the dataset

Comment: Nope unfortunately there would be no way of even approximating it without any more information. I know it's probably not what you're looking for, but your best solution would probably be to go to the Google trends website directly: https://trends.google.com/trends/?geo=US